# Universal Sentence encoder Error : tfhub_module.pb not found

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running python in Jupyter Lab 3.1.9. I would like to use Universal Sentence Encoder. Due to firewall setting I couldn't able to run the following command

```
embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3")
```

So I have downloaded the `TF2.0 Saved Model (v3)` & uploaded it on Jupyter Lab. Then I ran following command to unzip the file

```
import tarfile
file=tarfile.open('./universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual_3.tar.gz')
file.extractall('./Multilingual1')
```

Then I use following command to load the file

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed = hub.Module("./Multilingual1")
```

But I got following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2011/1867839697.py in <module>
      1 import tensorflow_hub as hub
      2 #embed = hub.Module("./Multilingual/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual_3.tar.gz")
----> 3 embed = hub.Module("./Multilingual1")
      4 
      5 #embed = hub.Module("universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual_3.tar.gz")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py in __init__(self, spec, trainable, name, tags)
    155     """
    156     self._graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
--> 157     self._spec = as_module_spec(spec)
    158     self._trainable = trainable
    159 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py in as_module_spec(spec)
     28     return spec
     29   elif isinstance(spec, str):
---> 30     return load_module_spec(spec)
     31   else:
     32     raise ValueError("Unknown module spec type: %r" % type(spec))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py in load_module_spec(path)
     63   """
     64   path = registry.resolver(path)
---> 65   return registry.loader(path)
     66 
     67 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/registry.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     49     for impl in reversed(self._impls):
     50       if impl.is_supported(*args, **kwargs):
---> 51         return impl(*args, **kwargs)
     52       else:
     53         fails.append(type(impl).__name__)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py in __call__(self, path)
    137 
    138   def __call__(self, path):
--> 139     module_def_proto = self._get_module_def_proto(path)
    140 
    141     if module_def_proto.format != module_def_pb2.ModuleDef.FORMAT_V3:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py in _get_module_def_proto(self, path)
    128     module_def_proto = module_def_pb2.ModuleDef()
    129     with tf.compat.v1.gfile.Open(module_def_path, "rb") as f:
--> 130       module_def_proto.ParseFromString(f.read())
    131     return module_def_proto
    132 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in read(self, n)
    112       string if in string (regular) mode.
    113     """
--> 114     self._preread_check()
    115     if n == -1:
    116       length = self.size() - self.tell()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in _preread_check(self)
     74         raise errors.PermissionDeniedError(None, None,
     75                                            "File isn't open for reading")
---> 76       self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
     77           compat.path_to_str(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
     78 

NotFoundError: ./Multilingual1/tfhub_module.pb; No such file or directory
```

Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Does the file ```Multilingual1/tfhub_module.pb``` exist?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. It contains only 1 `.pb` file, that is `saved_model.pb` I have downloaded the file `universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual_3.tar.gz` from https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Where is this ```tfhub_module.pb``` coming from?

Comment: I don't have any clue. I'm using universal-sentence-encoder for the first time. Because of firewall setting, I couldn't able to use it from website. So I have downloaded it & tried using the steps mentioned in my first post. Kindly suggest, if you think I should try it in some other way